# Can we destroy all references to an instance?

Tags: c#

If I have 10 `List<Car>`. Is there a way I can 'dispose' `CarInstance1` so it is removed from all the lists without having to search them one by one and do a `Remove()`?

Thank you!

Comment: I don't think so. And if so, it's probably not a good idea.

Comment: Lets assume there is a way to do it, doesnt this break the whole idea of managed code? what happens to the other 9 reference whose object is disposed? I'm sure it is impossible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no, each list stores a pointer/reference to that item. each list will need that reference to be removed.

Answer (score 2):

By "dispose" or "destroy", do you mean "remove the instance from the list"? If so, no, you must visit each list to remove the instances. There's no way to find all references to a given object (without using a profiler or debugger, at least).

Answer (score 1):

You can only change `CarInstance1` itself to have a different object reference, which would leave all other references to the original object unchanged - so no, you cannot do that.